# JavaScript for loop crashes browser

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

This loop crashes the browser when run, but I can't see why - function getN is one function of three designed to factorise quadratic equations.
I am sure it is the loop causing the problem, I have tested this and the browser only crashes when the for loop is present. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function getN(decP){
var a = document.getElementById("a-f").value;
var b = document.getElementById("b-f").value;
var c = document.getElementById("c-f").value;
var n_1 =0;
var n_2 =0;
var result = Math.pow(10, (decP*-1));
var a_c = a*c;
var neg_a_c = 0;
var pos_a_c = 0;
if(a_c<0){
    neg_a_c = a_c;
    pos_a_c = a_c*-1
}
else{
    pos_a_c = a_c;
    neg_a_c = a_c*-1;
}
for(x=neg_a_c;x<=pos_a_c;x+result){
    if(x!==0){
        if(x+(a_c/x)===b){
            var num1 = x;
            var num2 = a_c/x;
        }
    }
}
divideByCoefficient(num1, num2)
};
```

Comment: infinite loops tend to do that

Comment: `x+result` only evaluates the value, you are not storing it anywhere. Guess you want: `x+=result`

Answer (score 5):

```
for(x=neg_a_c;x<=pos_a_c;x+result){
                          ^
                           `-----here
```

You likely meant `x += result` (or `x = x + result`), not just `x+result`.

`x+result` never modifies `x`. So `x` always equals `neg_a_c` and the loop runs forever.